# How exactly works this example that use Angularfire2 to retrieve a list from a Firebase DB?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am not so into JavaScript\TypeScript and I have some problem to understand how exactly works this example used into an Angular application to retrieve data from a Firebase database. It works fine but I have some doubts about its logic (I think that it should be something related to functional programming paradigm and I am not so into this topic).

So I have this code that uses **Angularfire2** library (the new **^5.0.0-rc.4** version) to query my Firebase DB:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

   courses$: Observable<{}[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        console.log("TEST");

        this.courses$ = db.list('courses').snapshotChanges()
            .map(actions => {
                return actions.map(action => ({
                    $key: action.key,
                    value: action.payload.val(),
                }))
            });

        this.courses$.subscribe(console.log);
    }

}
```

So the `courses$` variable it shoul be an array of `Observable` (is it correct?). From what I know the `Observable` is an Object that emit events that can be subscribed. It will contain a list retrieved from Firebase DB.

This code section:

```
db.list('courses')
```

should simply create the binding with the `courses` node into my Firebase database (that contains itself a list of node) as a list. But I am not so sure if my interpretation is correct or if I am missing something.

Then on this binding is called the `snapshotChanges()` that should return an `Observable`.

Here I have the following doubts:

1. This `Observable` is related to a single element of the list of courses that I am retrieving or to the whole list of courses retrieved from the DB? (I think the second one but I am not so sure).
2. The exact type returned by the `snapshotChanges()` method seems to be `Observable<SnapshotAction[]>`. So what exactly means. It is an Observable that have an array of `SnapshotAction` as type. What exactly is and what exactly means?

Then there is this `map()` function:

```
.map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => ({
        $key: action.key,
        value: action.payload.val(),
    }))
});
```

Here I am pretty stuck...I think that it is the more functional section. I think that it used to create my output each time that something changes into the observed `courses$`.

Reading the documentation it seems that the `map()` method creates a new array (infact I am creating an array) with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

So it should mean that this is the function called on each element of array:

```
actions => {
    return actions.map(action => ({
        $key: action.key,
        value: action.payload.val(),
    }))
}
```

But what array? I think that it should be the previous `Observable<SnapshotAction[]>` returned by `snapshotChanges()` method.

I am absolutly not sure about this assertion....

So the idea is that every time that a change happens into the subscribed `courses$` observable the `map()` method is executed on the new data... But I think that I am missing a lot of intermediate stuff

How exactly does this work?

Comment: where did you see that example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges),

> AngularFire provides methods that stream data back as redux compatible
>   actions.

and `snapshotChanges` in particular:

> Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of
>   AngularFireAction[].

So this method returns an observable of array of DB actions.

Regarding the `map` function, here

```
return actions.map(action => ({
    $key: action.key,
    value: action.payload.val(),
}))
```

the example simply iterates over the array of actions and retrieves the data associated with each action from `action.payload.val()`. `map` here is not an observable operator, its a method on an array.

Answer (score 1):

observer subscribes to an `Observable`. Then that observer reacts to whatever item or sequence of items the `Observable` emits. This pattern facilitates concurrent operations because it does not need to block while waiting for the `Observable` to emit objects, but instead it creates a sentry in the form of an observer that stands ready to react appropriately at whatever future time the `Observable` does so.